# How to train several NER models (Spacy)

Tags: python, spacy, spacy-3

I'm training a custom named entity recognition model, I created the `config.cfg` and `train.spacy` files, among all it has, I'm using this as pre-trained vectors en_core_web_lg

```
[paths]
train = null
dev = null
vectors = "en_core_web_lg"
init_tok2vec = null
```

I then train the model using

```
!python -m spacy train config.cfg --output ./output --paths.train ./train.spacy --paths.dev ./train.spacy
```

This works and I can see the output model.

Then I want to train another NER model that has nothing to do with the previous one (same code different data) and I get this error:

```
Error: [E884] The pipeline could not be initialized because the vectors could not be found at 'en_core_web_lg'. 
If your pipeline was already initialized/trained before, call 'resume_training' instead of 'initialize', or initialize only the components that are new.
```

It looks like it modified the base en_core_web_lg model, which can be a problem for me since I use it for different models, some fine-tuned and others just out of the box.

How can I train this NER model making sure the downloaded en_core_web_lg model is not modified? and would this ensure that I can train several models without interfering with each other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use a model as a source of vectors, or for that matter a source for any other part of a pipeline, spaCy will not modify it under any circumstances. Something else is going on.

Are you perhaps using a different virtualenv? Does `spacy.load("en_core_web_lg")` work?

One thing that could be happening (but seems less likely) is that in some fields, you can use the name of an installed pipeline (using entry points) **or** a local path. If you have a directory named `en_core_web_lg` where you are training that could be checked first.

Comment: Hi, thanks. I realized there was something wrong with the folder that has the mode, and downloaded again and now it works